# Dimensions Don't Match for Decoder in Tensorflow Tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, dimensions

I am following the Convolutional Autoencoder tutorial for tensorflow, using tensorflow 2.0 and keras, found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder).

Using the provided code for building a CNN, but adding one more convolutional layer to both the encoder and decoder causes the code to break:

```py
class Denoise(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Denoise, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)), 
      layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2),
      layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2),
      ## New Layer ##
      layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)
      ## --------- ##
      ])

    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      ## New Layer ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      ## --------- ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(8, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
      ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = Denoise()
```

Running `autoencoder.encoder.summary()` and `autoencoder.decoder.summary()`, I can see this is a shape issue:

```
Encoder:
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_124 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_125 (Conv2D)          (None, 7, 7, 8)           1160      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_126 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 4)           292       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,612
Trainable params: 1,612
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Decoder:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_transpose_77 (Conv2DT (32, 8, 8, 4)             148       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_78 (Conv2DT (32, 16, 16, 8)           296       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_79 (Conv2DT (32, 32, 32, 16)          1168      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_127 (Conv2D)          (32, 32, 32, 1)           145       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,757
Trainable params: 1,757
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Why is the leading dimension on the decoding side `32`? Why wouldn't the dimensions of the incoming layer be `None, 4, 4, 4` if the inputs are passed from the encoder? How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `stride=2` in your last encoder layer, and add `stride=2` in your last decoder layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class Denoise(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Denoise, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)), 
      layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2),
      layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2),
      ## New Layer ##
      layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
      ## --------- ##
      ])

    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      ## New Layer ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      ## --------- ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(8, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', strides=2)
      ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = Denoise()
autoencoder.build(input_shape=(1, 28, 28, 1))
autoencoder.summary()
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Gervais! This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Keras uses 32 as the default batch_size. It might have something to do with this. But to fix this problem, you can include the `input_shape` argument in your decoder.

```
self.decoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      ## New Layer ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(4,4,4)),
      ## --------- ##
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(8, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')
      ])
```

Also, to avoid potential issues and consistency, I'd use `tf.keras.models` module for models (than `tf.keras.Model`) and `tf.keras.layers` for layers. It might not be a problem .. but could cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @thushv89! I'm still getting an issue when using `input_shape=(4,4,4)` with `tf.keras.layers` or with `layers` that my decoder dimensions are slightly off from the encoder dimensions, even though I've mirrored the steps. The following error is thrown: `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 28 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](denoise_42/sequential_71/conv2d_147/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [32,32,32,1], [32,28,28,1].`

Comment: That's because the final output of the decoder is size 32x32. Not 28x28. You'll need to resize the output size to 32x32 or will need to adjust the encoder and decoder with more appropriate input/output sizes that are continuously divisible by 2 (which is the stride)

Comment: Thank you so much @thushv89!